# React - How to fix edit function and submit button in todo list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started to learn React and I try to make a To do list. I stuck at editing items from the list.  This is how I see this. To edit single item I click on the "edit" button, input appears in the place of the item, I submit changes by hiting the "enter" button. 
My problem is

1. my function for submit button don't work (`handleEditingDone` - in the code).
2. when I click on the "edit" button `TypeError` appears

   > Cannot read property 'task' of undefined

   (handleEditing in the code)

App.js

```js
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todos: [
                // task: '',
                // id: '',
                //completed: false,
                // all of our to-dos
            ],
            todo: '',
            // an empty string to hold an individual to-do
            filtertodos: []
        }
    }



    inputChangeHandler = event => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    addTask = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let newTask = {
            task: this.state.todo,
            id: Date.now(),
            completed: false,
            editing: false
        };
        this.setState({
            todos: [...this.state.todos, newTask],
            todo: ''
        })
    }

handleEditing = (id) => {
        const todos = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
            if (todo.id === id) {
                todo.editing = !todo.editing
            }
            return todo
        });
        this.setState({
            todos : todos,
            todo: {
                changedText: this.todo.task,
            }
        })

    }
    handleEditingDone = event => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                todo: {                   // object that we want to update
                    editing: false,       // update the value of specific key
                }
            }));
        }
    }
    handleEditingChange = event => {
        let _changedText = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            todo: {changedText: _changedText}
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            todo: {changedText: this.todo.task}
        })
    }
```

Todo.js

```js
const Todo = props => {
        return (
            <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                {props.todo.editing ? (
                    <input onKeyDown={event => props.handleEditingDone} onChange={event => props.handleEditingChange}
                            type="text" value={props.changedText}/> )
                    :
                    (<p key={props.todo.id}
                       onClick={event => {
                           props.toggleComplete(props.todo.id)
                       }} >{props.todo.changedText}{props.todo.completed && ' Completed'}</p>)
                }
                <button onClick={event => props.handleEditing(props.todo.id)}>EDIT</button>
                <button onClick={event => {
                    props.onDelete(props.todo.id)
                }}>x
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: did you try <input onKeyDown={event => props.handleEditingDone(event)}? or simply <input onKeyDown={props.handleEditingDone}??

Comment: Hi, here what is this.todo.task is it any constant defined in the code?

Comment: Can you put your code in codesandbox(https://codesandbox.io/)?? . Its hard to tell from here

Comment: Here you can see code in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-satoshi-1gpz9?fontsize=14

Comment: @GibboK yes I've tryed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following:

```js
this.todo.task
```

There is no this.todo.
Try

```js
this.state.todo
```

Comment: I changed this line. Now I have this.state.todo. But my app still don't work. Now I can't see my "tasks" and when I click edit, I can't submit changes by clicking enter. https://imgur.com/sLUhuKD